# Scheduled task not running on boot

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have multiple drives, of which one is an NVME SSD and another is an HDD (WD RED). The HDD acts as a archive. I've set all my downloads to initially go to the NVME SSD and then I have a simple PS script that moves them to the HDD. I've scheduled this script to run at boot, but for some reason it's not even trying to run. Task history shows nothing. Manually running the task works like a charm.

The script:

```
Move-Item -Path "G:\Downloads\*" -Destination "D:\Downloads achive" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Execution policy:

```
PS C:\Users\admin> Get-ExecutionPolicy
RemoteSigned
```

General tab of the task:

[image: General]

Trigger tab of the task:

[image: Trigger]

Actions tab of the task:

[image: Actions]

What did I mess up?

Comment: Any traces in the Windows Event Log?

Comment: Is there a typo in `Downloads achive`? (*archive*).

Comment: Is there some reason you don't run this as the SYSTEM account?

Comment: One pitfall is that, due to running with elevation (highest privileges), the task process will not see your network drive mappings by default; if `G:` is a network drive, try using its UNC path instead.

Comment: If you are on domain joined machines, the UNC path just needs to be accessible with appropriate NTFS permissions to complete the "move" operations by domain group named "`Domain Computers`" and this usually allows machine AD object account and local machine `nt authority\system` access to the UNC path (both share and NTFS permissions need set). You can be machine explicit too if needed `<DESKTOP-SSDAESH>` (or use groups) for its `SYSTEM`. If "G" is a local partition, run task as `SYSTEM` and ensure it has access needed to all drives per applicable file object operations performed.

Comment: So from the `General` tab of the Task Scheduler job, select `Change User or Group` and type in `SYSTEM`, now test your job.